# Show that two finite two generator groups are isomorphic

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-isomorphism, combinatorial-group-theory

I was faced by a question that I can't solve. Any help would be great! Let $A$ and $B$ be groups with the following properties:

\begin{cases}
    |A| = 9 \cdot 3=27\\
A = \left<a,b\right> \\
a^{9} = e \\
b^{3} = e \\
ba = a^{4}b
\end{cases}

\begin{cases}
    |B| = 9 \cdot3=27\\
B = \left<\alpha,\beta\right> \\
\alpha^{9} = e \\
\beta^{3} = e \\
\beta\alpha = \alpha^{7}\beta
\end{cases}
I need to prove that $A \cong B$.
I really can't think of any isomorphism (or how to use some theorem) to solve this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What attempt have you made to solve the problem on your own? What tools do you have at your disposal?

Comment: @Carlo, I've know a theorem that guarantees that there is a isomorphism if some conditions are taken. The only condition that doesn't work here is that if there is $m$ and $n$ integers where $b^{m}=a^{n}$ then $\beta^{m}=\alpha^{n}$. Nothing but this! Thank you!

Comment: Would Tietze transformations be a good way of doing this? This comment is more of a question than a hint.

Comment: @SingleMalt unfortunately no, since I've never studied those transformations. But thank you anyway for your comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let’s drop the assumption that $A$ and $B$ have order $27$ (it is not needed). Consider the presentations:
$$\begin{align*}
A &= \langle a,b\mid a^9 = b^3=e,\ ba=a^4b\rangle\\
B &= \langle \alpha,\beta\mid \alpha^9=\beta^3=e,\ \beta\alpha=\alpha^7\beta\rangle.
\end{align*}$$
By von Dyck’s Theorem, we get a morphism from $A$ to $B$ by identifying two elements of $B$ that satisfy the same relations as $a$ and $b$ do, in $B$; and we get a morphism from $B$ to $A$ by identifying two elements of $A$ that satisfy in $A$ the same relations that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ do in $B$.

Consider the pair $(\alpha,\beta^2)$ in $B$. I claim that they satisfy the same relations in $B$ that $a$ and $b$ do in $A$. Indeed, $\alpha^9 =e$, $(\beta^2)^3= (\beta^3)^2 = e^2 = e$. And
$$\beta^2\alpha = \beta(\alpha^7\beta) = \alpha^{49}\beta^2 = \alpha\beta^2.$$
Thus, the map $a\mapsto \alpha$, $b\mapsto \beta^2$ extends uniquely to a morphism $A\to B$.

Now consider the elements $(a,b^2)$ in $A$. We claim they satisfyt the same relations as $\alpha$ and $\beta$ do in $B$. Indeed, we have $a^9 = e$, $(b^2)^3 = (b^3)^2 = e^2 = e$, and
$$b^2a = b(a^4b) = a^{16}b^2 = a^7b^2.$$
Therefore, the map $\alpha\mapsto a$ and $\beta\mapsto b^2$ extends uniquely to a morphism $B\to A$.

Now note that the two morphisms are inverses of each other: we have
$$\begin{align*}
a&\mapsto \alpha\mapsto a&\quad b&\mapsto \beta^2\mapsto (b^2)^2 = b\\
\alpha&\mapsto a\mapsto \alpha &\quad \beta&\mapsto b^2\mapsto (\beta^2)^2 = \beta.
\end{align*}$$
Thus, the two maps are isomorphisms, so $A\cong B$.

Now, we can show that $A$ and $B$ are in fact of order $27$. It’s easy to show $A$ has cardinality at most $27$ by showing every element can be written in the form $a^ib^j$, $0\leq i\lt 9$, $0 \leq j \lt 3$. And then we can consider the semidirect product $C_7\rtimes_{\phi} C_3$, with $C_7$ generated by $x$ and $C_3$ generated by $y$, and where $\phi\colon C_3\to \mathrm{Aut}(C_7)\cong C_6$ sends $y$ to the automorphism $x\mapsto x^4$. Then $x$ and $y$ in $C_7\rtimes_{\phi}C_3$ satisfy the same realtions as $a$ and $b$ to in $A$, so $a\mapsto x$ and $b\mapsto y$ extends to a homomorphism $A\to C_7\rtimes_{\phi} C_3$. Since $x$ and $y$ generate the latter, the morphism is surjective, so $|A|\geq 27$, proving the desired equality.

Comment: Liked a lot the way you proved the equality, I've never thought in that way. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Jeremy Rickard for his comments on my previous, incorrect, answer.

First, it's easy to prove by induction on $n$ that $ba^n=a^{4n}b$.  It's then easy to prove by induction on $k$ that $b^ka^n=a^{{4^k}n}b^k.$  Similarly, $\beta^k\alpha^n=\alpha^{{7^k}n}\beta^k.$  Thus, we observe that $b^2a=a^{16}b^2=a^7b^2$.  This observation motivates the following effort.

Define $\varphi:A \to B$ by $\varphi(a)=\alpha, \varphi(b)=\beta^2$.  It's easy to confirm that $\varphi(a^9)=\varphi(b)^3=1_B$, that $\varphi(a)$ in fact has order $9$, and that $\varphi(b)$ in fact has order $3$.  Also:

$$\varphi(ba)=\varphi(a^4b)=\varphi(a)^4\varphi(b)=\alpha^4\beta^2=\alpha^{49}\beta^2=\beta^2\alpha=\varphi(b)\varphi(a).$$

Thus, $\varphi$ is well-defined and a homomorphism, so $\varphi(A)$ is a subgroup of $B$, which meanns its order is a power of $3$ no greater than $27$.  But $\alpha \in \varphi(A) \Rightarrow \vert \varphi(A) \vert \geq 9$ and $\beta^2 \in \varphi(A) \setminus \langle \alpha \rangle$, so in fact $\vert \varphi(A) \vert \gt 9$.  It follows that $\varphi(A)=B$ and since $\vert A \vert = \vert B \vert, \varphi:A \to B$ is $1$-$1$, and hence is an isomorphism.

Comment: Hello, I just didn't understanded one thing: Why is true that
$\phi(a^{4}b)=\phi(a)^{4}\phi(b)$? Because at that point, $\phi$ is not proved as an homomorphism.

Comment: It's not that it's proved.  It's that you can define $\varphi$ to preserve products and it's still well-defined.  That demonstrates that, so extended, $\varphi$ is a homomorphism.